# Why is my laptop screen flickering white and grey?

Tags: laptop-display, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo Y500, I bought it two years ago. A while ago I got an issue where my screen started flickering with multicoloured stripes, I got the wiring repaired from a Lenovo store. I did this at my home just before leaving for college. There wasn't any Lenovo store around my college so I had to rely on a non-Lenovo service. That guy found a defect in the display panel itself. So he changed the display altogether. That fixed the issue for a while. But now I've got another issue. Whenever I start my laptop or wake it up from sleep, it starts to flicker white no light grey on two halves of the screen. I want to know about this before I go back to the guy who got me a new screen, because I feel he's making a fool out of me. Any clue what's causing it?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problems. First it appeared only from time to time. But then it became worse. In my case it was a damaged graphic chip. The solution would have been to let it repair through so called reballing, where the pins of the chip are resoldered (simply said). But in my case that was to expensive, because you had to disassemble the whole device. So I decided to buy me a new notebook.